# need help duplicating CSS styles

Tags: css

I am working on this site at https://newexplorers.co/ and I am having trouble duplicating the woo commerce css styles for the quantity plus and minus buttons in the modal after you click add to cart.

I want the buttons to look like this
https://newexplorers.co/product/lime-brown-plate
[image]

but, when I click the "add to cart" button on this page https://newexplorers.co/event/new-explorers-summer-camp-2023/ the buttons in the modal are not styled correctly.
[image]

I've added custom css but can't seem to get the styling right. The buttons are also not displaying correctly on a mobile device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly simple. please update the HTML for the button as shown in the screenshot below.

**What we did**

1: Add a wrapper for the button,
2: Add the '+/-' buttons inside the wrapper.
3: Make the wrapper relatively positioned

[image]

Comment: thanks this works as expected on desktop browser..when i look on my phone the styling is not there on the main page , in the modal the buttons are not there. any idea how i can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Add a absolute position for the plus/reduce button

Comment: this changes the styling on the main page before the modal

Comment: Can you add a selector for the above css take effect when the model is open@iambdot